# Find the smallest interval for parametric equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$\mathcal{G}$ is the graph of  parametric equations $\begin{align*} x = \cos(4t), y = \sin(6t). \end{align*}$.

Find the length of the smallest interval $I$ such that the graph of the parametric equations for all $t\in I$ produces the entire graph $\mathcal{G}$.

I am not very good with parametric equations so I am not sure where to begin. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the parametric graph on the intervals $0 \le t \le \pi/4$ it does an arc staring at $(1,0)$ to $(-1,-1)$ on the next $\pi/4 \le t \le \pi/2$ it retraces that arc back to $(1,0)$ for $\pi/2 \le t \le 3\pi/4$ it does an arc that is the reflection of the old arc traversed for $0 \le t \le \pi/4 $ on the $x$-axis. and finally for $3\pi/4 \le t \le \pi$ it is back to $(1,0)$ 
so the period is $\pi.$

Comment: What reflection are you referring to by "reflection of the old"?

Comment: If the period is $\pi$, then the length of the smallest interval is...$\pi$, too?

Comment: yes  @MathyPerson, the smallest interval is $\pi$ too.

Comment: hmm.. I tried it and $\pi$ was incorrect.

Comment: @MathyPerson, the graph is produced twice in that interval $0 \le t \le \pi.$ you can produce the graph in the shorter time $\pi/4 \le t \le 3\pi/4.$ the shortest interval has length $\pi/2.$

Answer (score 1):

According to M.G., you may want to have the x and y to repeat themselves, but they may have passed different number of periods, that is to say:
$$
\begin{cases}4t=n_1T\\6t=n_2T\end{cases}
$$ 
therefore：
$$
\frac{n_1}{n_2}=\frac{2}{3}
$$ 
$n_1=2$ is the minimum number for the equation, and $t=(1/4)(2)(2\pi)=\pi$ is the solution.

Comment: Best answer, since it is general! Is it correct to say that when looking for a period of parametric equations, we can find a period of each equation and then find the least common multiple - that is the period of the parametric equation?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Remember that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic functions with period $T=2\pi$.

Comment: Is it $[\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$?