# Smallest interval for graph

Tags: parametric

Parametric equation of a graph is x = cos(4t) , y = sin(6t) What is the length of the smallest interval $I$ such that the graph of these equations for all $t\in I$ produces the entire graph $\mathcal{G}$?

What is the process of finding smallest interval? My question is same as: [Find the smallest interval for parametric equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132738/find-the-smallest-interval-for-parametric-equations)

Here is what I tried: cos(4t) has period π/2 and sin(6t) has period π/3. I thought of taking LCM of [π/2, π/3] = π . But this doesn't seem to be the right answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does the answer to the linked question, and the comments below it, not solve your problem?

Comment: because I was solving this problem in an online website - Art of problem solving. After submitting the answer I get the response that π is not the correct answer.

Comment: The comments below that answer explain the actual answer and why

Comment: The comments below that answer give the correct answer, and why.